# Deploy jboss client jars to local maven repository

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a local jboss installation on my box and I would like to deploy the jars in the client directory to my local Artifactory server.

Is there are way do it in one single command, or should I deploy each single file individually?

What I don't want:

1. Using the JBoss nexus maven repository.
2. Add a proxy to JBoss nexus maven repo from my Artifactory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the jar files to be uploaded in a local repository folder layout, like:

> repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-spi/2.2.0-CR1/jboss-logging-spi-2.2.0.CR1.jar
>   repository/org/jboss/javaee/jboss-javaee/5.0.1.GA/jboss-javaee-5.0.1.GA.jar

Use the pom.xml from [here](https://gist.github.com/aleung/5194777) to batch upload them to maven repository by a single command `mvn install`.

Read my [blog post](http://aleung.github.io/blog/2013/03/19/maven-batch-deploy-artifacts/) for detail.